# sheet metal cutting measurements for ducts

Tags: cad

I need a software that generates the sheet metal cutting measurements for AC DUCT (AHU) most of them are T junctions and their diameters are uneven. I use AutoCAD to draw the sketch and measure the cutting limits but it is highly time-consuming.

so you have a good software that generates those values quickly? It would be great if it also can generate a sample image beside the values so anyone can understand it easily.

It should run on Linux or Windows. We always like free software :) Give me suggestions so I can buy it. Basically, I only need the measurements – and it should be practically cuttable in the real world easily. That is the only feature I need now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a program called [plate and sheet professional](http://www.plate-n-sheet.com/) that appears to cover a good portion of your requirements.

[image: pns image]

The site description notes that the results can be output in DXF for universal compatibility. The screen shots appear to provide the sample image you reference.

Fairly expensive, but not compared to something like an AutoCAD license. Over the past decade, I've not found anything comparable in the free or low-priced arena.

Comment: oh wow...now that is what I really wanted...thank you very much for the answer :)